# Typescript3.1.3 + Generics, error in type assignment

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript3.0

Consider this situation (dummy example):

```
class Farmer<A extends Animal<Farmer<A>>>
{
    public animal: A;
    constructor() {
        let a = new Animal(this);
        // ...
    }
}

class Animal<F extends Farmer<Animal<F>>>
{
    public farmer: F;
    constructor(f: F) {
        this.farmer = f;
    }
}
```

Anyone can explain why in the `Farmer` constructor (where I pass `this` argument to `new Animal`) the above code raises this error?

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Farmer<Animal<this>>'.
 Type 'Farmer<A>' is not assignable to type 'Farmer<Animal<this>>'.
  Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'Animal<this>'.
   Type 'Animal<Farmer<A>>' is not assignable to type 'Animal<this>'.
    Type 'Farmer<A>' is not assignable to type 'this'.
```

The following solve the issue:

```
class Farmer<A extends Animal<Farmer<A>>>
{
    public animal: A;
    constructor() {
        let a = new Animal(this as Farmer<A>); // works fine
    }
}
```

Or as alternative:

```
class Farmer<A extends Animal<Farmer<A>>>
{
    public animal: A;
    constructor() {
        let a = new Animal<Farmer<A>>(this); // works fine
    }
}
```

The more strange to me is the following:

```
class Farmer<A extends Animal<Farmer<A>>>
{
    // public animal: A; // removed this line
    constructor() {
        let a = new Animal(this); // now this one works fine too
    }
}
```

While first two solutions are quite clear, the latter is the one that leaves me more doubtful.
Can anyone explain what's happen?

**Edit**

The following is fine (consider optional the param in `Animal` constructor):

```
class Farmer<A extends Animal<Farmer<A>>>
{
    public animal: A;
    constructor() {
        let a = new Animal();
        a.farmer = this; // works fine
    }
}
```

And here I can't see any difference in types, compared with the first case.

Comment: Wow, usually in TypeScript you can sidestep [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) with [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), but here you have *mutually* recursive type parameters so you can't. The compiler can't verify that `A` is equivalent to `Animal<Farmer<A>>` (it only knows that `A` is a subtype of that) so it balks at `new Animal(this)` without those [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

Comment: The reason why the last solution "works" is because `Farmer<A>` no longer depends on `A` [structurally](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), which is all TypeScript really cares about.  That is, `Farmer<A>` and `Farmer<B>` are equivalent types, and there is no more mutual recursion to care about.

Comment: I'm not sure if someone has a cleaner solution that doesn't involve type assertions.. if not I'll turn these comments into an answer at some point.  Cheers

Comment: @jcalz, useful points. thanks. I edited the question adding another case.